# SDL C++ draw a 2D array into a quad

Tags: c++, sdl

How can i draw a 2D array of RGBA color floats/ints/etc... into a quad?

Not a square, but a shape where I can define the position of each of the four corners like in the image below.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you don't use SDL to do that.

---

The longer answer is that although SDL sets up and manages a lot for you, when it comes to the bulk of drawing you would have to [access the lower level API](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/51_SDL_and_modern_opengl/index.php).

To get that *specific transform* (and a whole host of others) you would draw the rects normally, but with a matrix operation that transforms the vertices.

In this day and age, you would do something along the following:

1. Create the quads you want to draw, with either their texture UVs or colors (or both) in a vertex array.
2. **Write a shader** that transforms the points in the array by a matrix, and then skins or fills the fragments.
3. Eat a taco
4. Bind all your data.. { vertices, textures, uniforms }
5. Draw your array.
6. All of the Above

Also, you'll want to change the perspective of the Window, or bake the perspective into the rotation matrix.  Things get more complicated when you want more 3D stuffs, like depth buffers, etc...

If you know a lot of OpenGL or DirectX, then using SDL as a jumping off point isn't a problem.

If you're not sure how a [matrix](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/OpenGL/13_matrix_transformations/index.php) would rotate the quads for you, then SDL is not for you.

---

[More Info](https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/under-sdl2-how-to-3d-rotate-a-image/21476/3)